# If $ |f(x)-f(y)| \leq 7|x-y|^{201} $ Then,

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for any two real numbers $x$ and $y$
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \leq 7|x-y|^{201}
$$
Then,

(A) $f(101)=f(202)+8$

(B) $f(101)=f(201)+1$

(C) $f(101)=f(200)+2$

(D) None of the above.

**My approach:-**

$$|(f(x)-f(y)|\leq 7|x-y|^{201}$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}|\leq 7| x-\left.y\right|^{200} \\ \lim_{x->y}\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right| \leqslant 7|x-y|^{200} \\ f^{\prime}(x) = 0 \\ f(x)=C, \quad \text { Accordingly } f(y)=C\end{array}
$$

So, option D is correct

Comment: it is correct. Replace $f'(x) \leq 0$ in the fourth line by $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|^\alpha$ then $f$ is called $\alpha-$Hölder, it is locally constant for $\alpha>1$, you can search these terms on MSE for more proofs (yet yours and copper hat's one are basically variants of all of them).

Comment: according to Hölder condition I can directly say a  function on an interval satisfying the condition with α > 1 is Constant....It will be more quick.Thanks indeed for your info

Comment: @AmartyaRoy  Note that your approach is good but not totally correct as you can't assume that the function is differentiable. As the answer by copper.hat shows, one can do something similar with finite differences to show the conclusion.

Comment: @Ingix: the bound $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\leq 7\left|x-y\right|^{200}$ clearly implies the differentiability.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Right, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for entertainment,

\begin{eqnarray}
|f(y)-f(x)| &=&  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |f( x+{k+1 \over n} (y-x)) ) - f( x+{k \over n} (y-x)) | \\
&\le&  7 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ({|y-x| \over n} )^{201} \\
&=& 7 {|y-x|^{201} \over n^{200}}
\end{eqnarray}

Letting $n \to \infty$ we see that $f(y)=f(x)$.